# Subplots not plotting correctly, matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I would like to have a 2x2 grid each being 8 times three bars next to each other.
Its because I have four evaluation parameter, each evaluation the quality of 8 languages for three models.

I was able to plot one of them, but it doesn't work for the other three being in my plot-grid.

At the moment, it looks like that:
[image]

```
eval_list = ["F1-Werte (micro)", "Precision", "Recall", "Accuracy"]
lang_list = ["Alle Sprachen", "Chinesisch", "Deutsch", "Englisch", "Finnisch", "Französisch", "Italienisch", "Spanisch"]

x = np.arange(start=1, stop=9, step=1)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,10), sharex=False)
df_list = list()
count = 0
for eval_elem in eval_list:
    flair = list()
    bert = list()
    roberta = list()

    for lang in lang_list:
        flair.append(dfBest.query("Eval==@eval_elem").query("Lang==@lang").query("Model=='multiflair'").iloc[0]['Average'])
        bert.append(dfBest.query("Eval==@eval_elem").query("Lang==@lang").query("Model=='bert'").iloc[0]['Average'])
        roberta.append(dfBest.query("Eval==@eval_elem").query("Lang==@lang").query("Model=='roberta'").iloc[0]['Average'])
    
    #ax = plt.subplot(2,2,count+1)
    
    a = 1 if count > 1 else 0
    b = 1 if count%2!=0 else 0
    
    axes[a][b].bar(x-0.2, flair, width=0.2, color='b', align='center')
    axes[a][b].bar(x, bert, width=0.2, color='g', align='center')
    axes[a][b].bar(x+0.2, roberta, width=0.2, color='r', align='center')

    plt.xticks(x, lang_list, rotation=90)
    plt.title(eval_list[count])
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1), labels=["multiflair", "bert", "roberta"])
    plt.show()
    count += 1
```

The three lists flair, bert and roberta represent the data and they all correctly put out a list of eight floats in each iteration, but otherwise I don't know, whats wrong with the layout.

Comment: I would try `axes = np.flatten(axes)`, get rid of `count` entirely, then `for n, eval_elem in enumerate(val_list): ...` `ax = axes[n]`. That way you don't bother with the 2D aspect of that list of Axes. Then, get rid of all `plt.` based functions and put `ax.` everywhere. remove `plt.show()` from the loop and add `fig.show()` after it.

Comment: I would throw `bar_kwargs = dict(width=0.2, align='center')` and `ax.bar(..., ..., **bar_kwargs)` in there as well for compacity, since those parameters are shared between all bars.

Comment: What do you mean with the np.flatten command? It tells me that numpy didn't have such a command (while I know, that it must exist)

Comment: The rest is understandable, thank you for your feedback and the idea with bar_kwargs

Comment: Ah yes my bad, `flatten` is a `ndarray` method and not a module function. `axes = np.array(axes).flatten()` then. It will turn `[[ax0, ax1], [ax2, ax3]]` into `[ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3]` so that it's easier to iterate on.

Comment: I have learned a lot. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: @Perfect! You too :-)